# Check if a list has uppercase or lowercase letters or numbers in a list in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

How can i create a function that checks 
if a list has at least one uppercase or lowercase letters,  (and may contain numbers in a list) in racket

and contains no special characters (no spaces, no special characters)

```
(alphabet (list "abc" "ABC" "aBC" "AbC")) ⇒ true
```

```
(list "9wa123re1" "0w1e2a3r4")) ⇒ true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket

;; for one string is the test:
(define (alpha-and-perhaps-numeric? s)
  (regexp-match #rx"^([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+$" s))

;; for a list of strings is the test:
(define (alpha-list? l)
  (for/and ((x l))
    (alpha-and-perhaps-numeric? x)))
```

- `[0-9]*` means: zero or more (`*`) numeric (`[0-9]`)
- `[a-zA-Z]+` means: at least one or more (`+`) lower or uppercase alphabetic (`[a-zA-Z]`)
- `[0-9]*` possibly followed by zero or more numbers.
- `( )+` This whole construct matched at least once if not more times.
- `^ $` ensures that this thing matches from beginning to end of string without gaps.
  So any other string not buildable with this pattern will return `#f`.
  (any non-alphanumeric character containing string).

Comment: Im sorry what language is this in. I am not familiar with this language.

Comment: @loren plain racket. `#rx" "` denotes regular expression strings. This is built-in in racket. It is shortly called "regex". Many programming languages have it in-built as domain specific languages for strings.

Comment: Thank you for this but I have not learned built in functions yet, just basic functions.

Comment: Sorry but this still using abstract functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket 

(define (alpha+-num? clst (acc #f) (alpha 0))
  (cond ((null clst) (and (not (zero? alpha)) acc))
        ((char-alphabetic? (car clst)) (alpha+-num? (cdr clst) #t (+ alpha 1)))
        ((char-numeric? (car clst)) (alpha+-num? (cdr clst) acc alpha))
        (else #f)))

(define (alpha+-num-string? s)
  (alpha+-num? (remove-duplicates (string->list s))))

(define (alpha+-num-string-list? sl (acc #f))
  (cond ((null sl) acc)
        ((alpha+-num-string? (car sl)) (alpha+-num-string-list? (cdr sl)))
        (else #f)))
```

What you want is `alpha+-num-string-list?`

Answer (score 0):

```
(define check-lower-char
  (lambda (input)
    (andmap (lambda(s)
              (andmap (lambda (c)
                        (or (not (char-alphabetic? c))
                            (char-lower-case? c)))
                      s))
            (map string->list input))))


(check-lower-char (list "abc" "ABC" "aBC" "AbC")))  ;; => #f
(check-lower-char (list "9wa123re1" "0w1e2a3r4"))   ;; => #t
```